# Flutter alert dialog

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is there a way to do a popup or a show dialog displaying an error message for the case of invalid entry in a textfield? Here is the code and output, please kindly suggest me something.

Code:

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Email',
    hintStyle: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 14,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
      color: Hexcolor('#9fa6b4'),
    ),
    border: InputBorder.none,
    prefixIcon: Icon(
      Icons.mail,
      color: Hexcolor('#9fa6b4'),
    ),
  ),
  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
  validator: (value) {
    if (value.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
      return 'Invalid email!';
    }
  },
  onSaved: (value) {
    _authData['email'] = value;
  },
),
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: in the output image you posted there is no "alert dialog", do you mean that red text: "invalid email!" placed at the bottom left of the field?

Comment: @pskink. I wanted to display that error message "Invalid email" in a popup or in a dialog box. Can you help me with this?! Thanks for your response

Comment: so call `showDialog` function but honestly `BottomSheet` works better for such cases

Comment: @pskink where do I call the showDialog. Here the return statement expects a string. Do I update the code so you can have a better look?!

Comment: sorry I mean `SnackBar` not `BottomSheet` - read the docs on how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Before adding Dialog you must call showDialog function to change current screen state to show the intermediate Dialog popup.
In here we use AlertDialog widget to show simple Dialog with title and some text in the body.

```
showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context){
                  return AlertDialog(
                    title: Text("Alert Dialog"),
                    content: Text("Dialog Content"),
                  );
              }
            )
```

Under the content, it does not required to add only the Text, you can add any widget like Image or something. But Because we use Alert Dialogs in simple use case, it better to show simple text or an image inside the content.

In here we need to close the current Dialog when clicking Close button.
We can use the pop method in Navigator class for that.

```
FlatButton(
             child: Text("Close"),
             onPressed: (){
             Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
      )
```